# How to use grepl with a character vector length greater than one?

Tags: regex, grepl, rr

Trying to create a conditional `dummy variable (c)` which converts `b >= x` to `c = 1` and `b < x` to `c = 0`.

An example output when `x = 3`:

```
a b c
1 1 0
2 3 1
3 4 1
4 2 0
```

```r
df$c<-ifelse(grepl(b[b <= 3], df$b), as.numeric(1), as.numeric(0))
```

I've tried using the above `ifelse()` function, but `grepl` allows for a character of only length 1:

> In grepl(b[b <= 3],df$b) :
>   (argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used)

Comment: `df$c <- as.integer(df$b >= 3)` Or more generally `df$c <- as.integer(df$b >= x)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your a bit confused with `grepl` and how (and when) regular expressions are used. Regular expressions are used to find patterns in strings (such as figuring wheter "b", "d", or "g" a part of variable `b`, one could use `grepl("[bdg]", b, ignore.case = TRUE)`). If `b` is numeric, you use conditional statements (as you have).

Basically you could use

```
df$c <- with(df, ifelse(b <= 3, 1, 0))
```

or

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$b <= 3, 1, 0)
```

or similarly using transform

```
df <- transform(df, c = ifelse(b<=3, 1, 0))
```

The confusion is likely that you are trying to figure out `which` of the ifelse statement is 1 or 0. For this you could use `which`

```
df$c <- 0
df$c[which(b <= 3)] <- 1
```